# Getting all Keystrokes typed by user in Android

Tags: android

Is there a way to log all the keystrokes typed by the user in an Android device. I am not asking this for any spying purpose. I am just wondering if this can be done in Android, if so how ? I came across an App [Type Machine](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fi.rojekti.typemachine) which does this, and is it available in PlayStore. How does android allow such things ?

The [Type Machine](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fi.rojekti.typemachine) app says that it uses the **Android accessibility framework** to achieve this. Anyone knows how this can be done ?

Comment: Sure, detecting input is necessary for a number of applications, as is storing data. To block them would create a headache for devs and Google both, so they just don't. Even logging in the device doesn't do anything really it's sharing it through a network that can be bad.

Comment: Any idea how can it be done ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/commands.html